# How to take the high part of __m256

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, intrinsics, avx

i have  __m256 or __m256i, i want to take the higher part.

Given `__m256 variable`, I know i can do that with   `_mm256_extractf128_ps(variable, 1)`

but for the low part : `_mm256_extractf128_ps(tr3, 0)` is better do that 
`*((__m128*)&variable)`

I don't know how  to take the high part using some pointers with the same way i used before for the low part?

Can I add  a number or increment the pointer ?
`*((__m128*)&variable+128)`

Comment: `*((__m128*)&variable + 1)`. It's simple C pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Jester Technically undefined behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: @fuz: actually no; `__m128` is a may_alias type, like `char`.  It is actually safe to deref a `__m128*` that points into a `__m256` object.  I wouldn't recommend it, though.

Answer (score 3):

**`_mm256_extractf128_ps(v, 1)` is the best way**.  If you compiler doesn't compile that efficiently, use a better compiler (e.g. clang has a very good shuffle optimizer).

For the low half, all compilers optimize `_mm256_extractf128_ps(v, 0)` to not actually use a `vextractf128` instruction, but the most explicit way with intrinsics to say you just want to low 128 is [`_mm256_castps256_ps128`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,AVX_512,Other&expand=1879,622&text=_mm256_cast) and similar casts for `__m256i` (`_mm256_castsi256_si128`) or `__m256d`.

These normally compile to just using the XMM low half of whatever YMM register the compiler had the vector variable in, although some compilers have missed optimization bugs and sometimes emit a useless `vmovaps xmm, xmm` instruction instead of just having later instructions read either the low xmm or the full ymm of whatever register.

Using pointer math kind of encourages the compiler to store and reload, which you usually don't want.  But in practice most compilers will most of the time optimize it back to ALU shuffles, even if you were trying to avoid a shuffle-port bottleneck and actually do a store/reload.

---

**I don't recommend pointer casting**.  However, `*((__m128*)&variable)` and `((__m128*)&variable)[1]` are legal because intrinsic vector types such as `__m128` are like `char` - they're allowed to alias any other type without violating strict aliasing and causing Undefined Behaviour.

C pointer math moves the pointer by 1 size unit of the pointed-to type. e.g. `+1` on a `__m128*` moves by 16 bytes, which is one `__m128`.  This is why `++` always works to iterate a pointer over an array.  [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Since you want the 2nd `__m128`, you should add `1` to your `__m128*`.  e.g. `*(1 + (__m128*)&variable)`.  C `[]` syntax [is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617693/how-do-square-brackets-work-in-c) in terms of pointer addition + dereference, so we can write it that way, applying `[]` to the cast result.  Both these orders of writing it make it 100% clear that the `+1` applies to the `__m128*` after the cast, not to the `__m256` from `&var` before the cast.  Although IIRC, casting has higher precedence than `+1` to `*((__m128)&var + 1)` would also be safe.  But writing it the other way means you don't have to remember that when reading code later.

---

In GNU C, intrinsic types are defined with `__attribute__((may_alias))`.  In MSVC, aliasing is always allowed.  [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond)  This is what makes the pointer-casting safe for this type punning.

Any *other* type, like `((float*)&vec)[0]` would violate strict aliasing and be UB.

As I said, since you normally want the compiler to use shuffle instructions, messing around with pointers requires the compiler to optimize away all the pointers.  Use intrinsics.

Comment: Update: pointing a `float*` at a vector of `float` elements (`__m256`) might be legal in GNU C.  GCC and clang define `__m256` as `typedef float  __m256 __attribute__((vector_size(32),may_alias))`. But there's very little reason to rely on that when you could use an extract intrinsic or just store to a tmp array (so the `__m256` can live only in a register instead of itself getting spilled to stack space so a `float*` can point into it, assuming things get compiled literally; either way can actually optimize into a shuffle.)